# Firebase Admin SDK cant upload to storage bucket folder

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, multer, firebase-admin

im trying to upload file using firebase function, multer using [this docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/) but it seems i cant upload to folder firebase like this pict :

[...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv2F5.png)

i want to upload directly to my folder
i already try this

```
const bucket = storage.bucket("<my-bucket>.appspot.com/img_users/");
```

but still not worked, Please Help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no concept of folder or subdirectory in Cloud Storage. The `img_users/` "folder" you see in the Firebase console is actually generated from the file name of one or more files which have a file name composed as follows:

`img_users/<rest_of_the_file_name>`

The Firebase console creates "fake" folders based on the parts of the file name separated by some slashes (`/`). In other words, the console "makes it appear" that the above file resides in the `img_users/` "folder", but to Cloud Storage, the object simply exists in the bucket and has the name shown above. You will find more detailed explanations in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-objects#object-considerations).

The consequence of this behaviour is that you should not include the "folder" name in the String you pass to the `bucket()` method, but include it when you create a file Reference.