# Flutter Firebase Upload with Authentication

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload a profile photo as a logged in user with the following however I get error

```
E/flutter (32619): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action.
```

**My code**

```
 User? user = await authenticationService.getCurrentUser();

    // Create a Reference to the file
    Reference ref =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(user!.uid).child('/profile.jpg');

    final metadata = SettableMetadata(
        contentType: 'image/jpeg',
        customMetadata: {'picked-file-path': s!.path});

    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(File(s.path), metadata);

    var result = await uploadTask;
    print(result);
```

**My rule**

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.+');
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: try doing if request.auth != null instead of if request.auth.uid == userId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to upload a file to the following reference

```
FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(user!.uid).child('/profile.jpg');
```

and check, in the security rules, that the id of the user executing the upload corresponds to the value of `user!.uid`.

In your security rules, you have a check as `request.auth.uid == userId` but nowhere in the rules you define what is `userId`. You need to use a [wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/core-syntax#match_wildcards), as follows:

```
service firebase.storage {
  // The {bucket} wildcard indicates we match files in all Cloud Storage buckets
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    
    match /{userId}/{imageId} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.+');
    }
  }
}
```

---

If you only upload images named `profile.jpg` in this "[folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65483628/firebase-admin-sdk-cant-upload-to-storage-bucket-folder/65483907#65483907)", you could add a check like `imageId == 'profile.jpg'` but you could also define the path as:

```
    match /{userId}/profile.jpg {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
                   && request.resource.contentType.matches('image/.+');
    }
```